# Aggregating 2 Tables in tSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

I am using sybase.

I have two tables like this:

```
USER | HITS
------------
 A   |  2
 B   |  1
 C   |  4
 E   |  3


USER | HITS
------------
 A   |  2
 B   |  8
 C   |  1
 D   |  2
```

I want to combine them on USER and SUM the HITS column to get a result like this:

```
USER | HITS
------------
 A   |  4
 B   |  9
 C   |  5
 D   |  2
 E   |  3
```

I was able to combine them partially, using this query:

```
select a.USERNAME, sum(a.HITS+b.HITS)
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.USERNAME=b.USERNAME
group by a.USERNAME
```

I am not sure what to do to get the whole data set I want... I'm having trouble when trying to use a JOIN or UNION...  please help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT USER, SUM(HITS) HITS
FROM
(SELECT USER, HITS
FROM Tbl1 UNION ALL
SELECT USER, HITS
FROM Tbl2) A
GROUP BY USER
```

Comment: could you explain the significance of the "A" following the sub select in your query?  I'm not sure I understand what it's doing,,,

Comment: "A" is just an alias, in the `sybase` dialect is correlation name of the derived table.

Comment: oohh. I see. Thats why I was getting a reference error when I do not include the table alias... THANKS!! :D

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if Sybase has `with`, if not you can nest the subquery as per Hamlet's solution.

```
;with x (user, hits) as (
    select
        user, hits
    from
        table1
    union all
    select
        user, hits
    from
        table2
)
select
    user,
    sum(hits) as hits
from
    x
group by
    user;
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of results are you not getting? Try this, I prefer this format because it is easie to read

select a.USERNAME, sum(a.HITS+b.HITS)
from table1 a Inner join table2 b On a.username = b.username
group by a.USERNAME

Comment: `INNER JOIN` won't work because of the differences in `table A` & `table B` (see User's E & F). Normally I would suggest using a `FULL OUTER JOIN` but apparently Sybase does not support this syntax. http://www.dbforums.com/sybase/1634212-full-join-sybase.html

Comment: I didn't even notice that. Good catch!